# Clarification needed for various architect terms and their roles

Tags: architecture

After going through many SO questions and answers on "Architects" , I am now basically confused with the various terms and their roles. Could any one please explain the terms clearly and their roles

```
A) Technical Architect

B) Solution Architect

C) Domain Architect

D) Enterprise Architect 

E) Project Architect

F) Systems Architect

G) Software Architect

H) Design Architect
```

Thanks

Comment: Easy: they all build houses.

Answer (score 4):

Domain Architect, Project Architect and Design Architect aren't terms I've ever come across.  I have (very occassionally) met the odd UI Architect. Systems Architect isn't one I've seen in much use.

The way I think about (most of) these roles is like this:

[image]

I'd also suggest checking out Wikipedia for more detailed definitions.